# Scrolling going the opposite direction in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, scrolling

I'm just using a regular desktop. Chrome is scrolling the wrong way and it is driving me CRAZY!

Comment: Is it Chrome or Chromium? Also, could you specify what's the problem with scrolling more precisely? This could be a bug in Chromium, that's why...

Comment: I suspect this is an OS X Lion user who wants scrolling to work the wrong way :-)

Comment: When a scroll bar goes down you're pulling the page up that's how it's suppose to be not dragging the scroll bar down and pulling the page down, so nothing is broken.

Comment: @Chris: Please explain exactly what your problem is; "scrolling the wrong way" isn't specific enough for us to figure out.

Comment: Sorry folks i was having a bad day. It was ubuntu and i figured out the problem. Natural scrolling was on in ubuntu tweak but it only affected google chrome nothing else.

Comment: @Chris I recommend [posting an answer explaining the resolution](http://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer). This will help others with similar problems who search and find this. (They'll see it's answered and see a prominent answer that may help them.)

Comment: I do not know what the problem actually looks like, but sometimes unplug the mouse fron the USB port and plug again works...

Answer (score 1):

As @Chris mentioned in [this comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159181/need-to-fix-scrolling-in-chrome#comment195019_159181), Ubuntu Tweak had activated **Natural Scrolling** which worked just in Chrome. Disabling the option fixed the problem.